# Minecraft timed command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I currently run a Minecraft server along with some other people, with the new addition to Discord nitro server boosting we'd like to give people who boost our discord a reward.

The plan is to make a discord Nitro rank in the Minecraft server, this rank will expire in 7 days (the amount of time the discord server boost lasts) and then it will restore them to their rank they had before being added to the Nitro group. The problem is how do we make it so the command (if using group manager) waits 7 days without having to manually add them back into their previous rank?

For example, after being the Nitro rank for 7 days and having their server boost run out, how would we automatically add them back to their previous rank, the rank they had before they bought the Nitro rank? The command would be simple, `/manuadd (player name) (Rank before being added to nitro)`, but the million dollar question is how do we make that command wait 7 days before activating? Which is the overall question in this. How do we make a command, and set a timer for it to go off in a given period of time.

We've got a multitude of plugins on the server, and are able to download plugins if needed.

Comment: Does this work together with vanilla commands? Can you use `/manuadd` in an `/execute` command and can you use vanilla target selectors (@a and @s in this case)? If so, what version of minecraft do you use? `/execute` changed a lot for 1.13+.

Answer (score 1):

### This answer utilizes plugins, and is not applicable to vanilla servers.

I'm not as familiar with GroupManager, but it seems that the plugin does not offer a "temporary rank" feature.

Considering you can use plugins, use the *timed permissions* feature offered by [PermissionsEX](https://github.com/PEXPlugins/PermissionsEx).

```
pex user <user> group add <group> [world] [time]
```

where `time` parameter is measured in seconds. To add the group to the user globally, use `*` in the `world` parameter.

Alternatively, there are many plugins dedicated to timed permissions and groups.

Note 1: PEX is unmaintained at the moment, but it works for most servers. A popular alternative is [LuckPerms](https://github.com/lucko/LuckPerms) which has a migration feature.

Note 2: Nitro Server Boosts don't expire after 7 days. A server boost stays indefinitely until the booster chooses to boost another server.